# Manually uninstall an application by removing files (tried dpkg -r/P with no success)

Tags: 18.04, dpkg, filesystem, uninstall

I installed tmetric by `dpkg -i tmetric_desktop_18.2.4_amd64.deb`. 
Nice and everything, although it doesn't really work well with Bionic. I therefore tried to remove it.

Here's where it gets weird. Even though `dpkg -P tmetric{,-desktop}` went through  (no results were found for tmetric alone), after rebooting some tmetric GUI popped up asking whether I wanted to track my time.

As you can imagine, this is quite disturbing for me, as I suspect there might be some automatic process running on the background which could potentially gather connection and share my data.

After that, I removed /usr/bin/tmetric (which turned out to be still there despite having tried all dpkg and apt -r and -P options), and I now want to make sure all traces of tmetric are gone.

So my question is: What is the list of all possible locations to check for some tmetric* file/folder?
Is it safe to remove it automatically? (I wonder whether trying something like `find / -name tmetric* -delete` would be suitable in this case) perhaps with some confirmation flag before it.

Also, I just realized that ~/.Devart just reappeared (dir for tmetricdesktop settings including my email address, "refresh-token" and active time). Please! I want to get rid of this nasty application asap!

[image: popup screenshot (on the right)]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What does this give you `dpkg -l tmetric`? To find the files `sudo dpkg -L tmetric`! Look for the process id and kill it with `sudo pgrep tmeric` then sudo kill -9 <PID>`

Comment: Oh yes, I tried that, with no results. I believe dpkg is just completely unaware of its existence. And still, the tracking prompt just reappeared 5 seconds ago!
Thanks for asking!

Comment: Did this `sudo pgrep tmeric` turn up anything?

Comment: Didn't know this command, unfortunately no. (I ran `sudo pgrep tmeTric`)

Comment: run `sudo find / -iname "*tmetric*"`!

Comment: `locate tmetric`. Or, re-download `tmetric_desktop_18.2.4_amd64.deb` and `dpkg-deb --contents tmetric_desktop_18.2.4_amd64.deb` to get a list of files that were installed earlier.

Comment: After running `sudo find / -iname "*tmetric*"` , I found `/etc/xdg/autostart/tmetricdesktop.desktop` and removed it, along with `~/.Devart`. Also @waltinator 's tip will likely prove helpful in the future. Once I'll be sure that the problem is solved, I might write an answer to this same q. However, the state of my solution is not quite as structured as to provide rigorous help for others. Should I write what _I think_ solved it anyway?
Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Just

```
sudo apt remove tmetricdesktop
```